# SQL Joining column is a subset of another

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assuming the following tables:

```
Table A
[Description]
Some Apples are Green
Many Bananas are Yellow
Carrots are Orange

Table B
[Color]
Apples
Bananas
Carrots
```

I would like to `inner join` these tables where `B.[Color]` is a subset of `A.[Description]`

Results would be

```
[Description]            [Color]
Some Apples are Green    Green
Many Bananas are Yellow  Yellow
Carrots are Orange       Orange
```

Comment: please tag the rdbms you are using like SQLServer,mysql,oracle,postgres...

Comment: @TheGameiswar done thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[Demo Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/523192)</kbd>

This doesn't involve like condition

```
select dataa,b.colorname from #temp t
cross apply
(select  replace(t.dataa,colorname,'') as rplc,colorname
from #colors)b
where dataa<>rplc
```

Comment: I just cleaned up a bit for clarity....that was fantastic thanks again.... https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/523183

Comment: Thanks,i have added some dummy data roughly,i will use the modified data fiddle in answer

Answer (score 0):

Although TheGameiswar's solution is really cool **AND MORE EFFICIENT** .... Here's another simpler solution for a small subset of data.

```
select * from
#A
inner join  #B
on [description] like '%'+color+'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the easiest solution, unless performance may be an issue:

```
SELECT Description, Color
FROM TableA ta
INNER JOIN TableB tb ON ta.Description LIKE '%' + tb.Color
```

Note I'm considering the description ends with the color. If that's not always the case you need to add another % at the end.